# Write PySpark DF to File of Specialized Format

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, cntk

I'm working with PySpark 2.1 and I need to come up with a way to write my dataframe to a .txt file of a specialized format; so not the typical json or csv, but rather a CTF format (for CNTK).

The file cannot have extra parenthesis or commas etc.  It follows the form:

```
|label val |features val val val ... val
|label val |features val val val ... val
```

Some code to show this might be as follows:

```
l = [('Ankit',25),('Jalfaizy',22),('saurabh',20),('Bala',26)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x[0], age=int(x[1]))).toDF()
people.show(n=4)

def Convert_to_String(r):
    return '|label ' + r.name + ' ' + '|features ' + str(r.age) + '\n'

m_p = people.rdd.map(lambda r: Row(Convert_to_String(r)) ).toDF()
m_p.show(n=3)
```

In the above example, I would want to simply append each string from each row into a file with out any extra characters.

The real data frame is quite large; It is likely ok for it to be split into multiple files; but would be preferable if the result were a single file.

Any insights is quite helpful.

THANKS!

Comment: Can't you simply call `m_p.saveAsTextFile(path)`? The output would likely be split into multiple files, but you can concatenate them together quite easily. I used to do something similar where I'd write my text files to HDFS and combine them afterwords using `hadoop fs -cat path/* > combined.txt`.

Comment: saves empty if I do that.  m_p.rdd.saveAsTextFile("wasb://data-files@MINE.blob.core.windows.net/traindata/train_test.ctf")

Comment: Hmm. I just noticed that your in your map function, your converting the row to a string and then back to a `Row` to convert it to a DF. What about just mapping to a list of strings using (maybe using `flatMap`): `m_p = people.rdd.flatMap(lambda r: Convert_to_String(r))`

Comment: That seems to do what I want :D.  The smaller data set creates several empty files, but on the big one should probably be good.  Testing on big one now. :D

Comment: Had to make a very small change in the string converter: def row_to_ctf_string(r):
    s = '|label ' + str(r['_7'][0]) + ' '
    s = s + '|features ' + str(r['_1'][0]) + ' '
    s = s + str(r['_2'][0]) + ' '
    s = s + str(r['_3'][0]) + ' '
    s = s + str(r['_4'][0]) + ' '
    s = s + str(r['_5'][0]) + ' '
    s = s + str(r['_6'][0]) + ' '
    return s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer.

Instead of converting each record to a `Row` and calling `toDF()`, just map each record to a string. Then call `saveAsTextFile()`.

```
path = 'path/to/output/file'

# depending on your data, you may need to call flatMap
m_p = people.rdd.flatMap(lambda r: Convert_to_String(r))

# now m_p will contain a list of strings that you can write to a file
m_p.saveAsTextFile(path)
```

Your data will likely be stored in multiple files, but you can concatenate them together from the command line. The command would look something like this:

```
hadoop fs -cat path/to/output/file/* > combined.txt
```